# Questionnaire database design?

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

I need to create a simple questionnaire ER diagram. It is gonna be Health Risk assessment questionnaire and assess health risk of a patient. Each tuple will include questionnaireID, PatientID, DoctorID and Answers of each question like answer1,answer2,...etc. and also each answer can be Y/N , checkbox or dropdown list. I need to consider questionnaire page by page. It can be three pages.Please help me asap.

Answer (score 2):

The organization on the page is a view consideration.  I wouldn't worry about that in designing the schema.

You might have parent/child questions (e.g., don't ask pregnancy questions if gender is male; only ask cancer questions if the patient has had cancer, etc.)

A questionnaire might have associated history: Questions might be added or removed on given dates.  I'd add effective and expiration dates for each question.

A questionnaire has one ore more questions.

A question can have one or more candidate answers (e.g. multiple choice), but only one given or selected answer.

An answer can have a type.  Each type will have its own table, with a foreign key relationship to its type and question.

A decision tree/hierarchy might work better than relational tables.  This could be a good use for XML and NoSQL.

These might help you design your schema.  Good luck.

Comment: I am a mathematician and so new in CS. I need to create Er diagram for that questionnaire

Comment: Get a shovel.  I hope you don't think I'm going to create it for you.

Comment: HOW ABOUT PAGES IN THE QUESTIONNAIRE DO I NEED TO CREATE A PAGE TABLE?? THANKS

Comment: I DON'T THINK SO!  PAGES ARE A VIEW CONSIDERATION, IN MY OPINION!  TURN OFF YOUR CAPS LOCK!  IT LOOKS LIKE YOU'RE SHOUTING!  IT'S CONSIDERED RUDE ON THE INTERNET!